# Ошибка в новой службе

Tags: windows, powershell, службы

Создал скрипт на powershell

```
while ($true) {
$ipv4 = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:computername -count 1).ipv4address.IPAddressToString
$num = $ipv4.split(".")[-1]
$ie = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.******/indata.php?nt=$num" -Method POST -ContentType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
Wait-Event -Timeout 3
}
```

Создал новую службу по запуску скрипта а он ругается, кто может подсказать в чем дело?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт не является исполняемым файлом. Вам следовало бы поставить в качестве исполняемого файла `powershell.exe`, а скрипт передать ему параметром:

```
powershell -file d:\path\file.ps1
```

Но это тоже не будет работать, поскольку от службы винда требует специальный протокол взаимодействия с контроллером служб, и на powershell реализовать его невозможно. Вам нужно найти готовую программу-враппер, чтобы сделать свой скрипт службой (или же можно написать свою службу на C#), гуглите по ключевым словам *"windows service wrapper"*.

Но проще всего использовать планировщик заданий вместо службы.

Comment: Например http://nssm.cc/ ?